# Виджет погоды

Tags: виджет, css, javascript

Как мне сделать виджет погоды на сайте с автоопределением города, и самое важное, чтобы можно было самому стилизовать его.

[image]

Comment: возьмите виджет погоды у поставщика метеоданных, в его доке будет написано как его стилизовать.

Comment: Не подскажите, какой именно? А то у всех стоит запрет на изменение виджета.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2ya9vzrp/1/

Comment: вообще супер отлично, только вот вопрос, а автоопределения города нету? А то, как я понял, надо кликать, чтобы выбрать определенный город

Comment: нет. тут колдунство с GeoIP надо